# Azure AKS cluster node disk type

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have AKS cluster and I would like to check a node disk type. I know there  are 4 types of disk at the moment: standard HDD, standard SSD, premium SSD and ultra SSD (in preview). The node itself is set up to be `Standard_DS2_v2` (via terraform) but there is no option (or I dont see it) for setting up certain disk type. How can I check disk type on Kubernetes node(s)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Terraform, just like the Azure portal and `az aks create`, only allows you to select a predefined VM size.

[Standard_DS2_v2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes-general#dsv2-series) has "Premium SSD". All AKS nodes use SSD storage, in the provided link the ones with "Premium SSD" are listed as "Premium Storage: Supported".

Alternatively in the Azure Portal, create a new AKS resource (no need to really create it, just open the wizard), then in the first step, click the link "Change size" next to "Node size" and you'll get a list of available VM sizes with a column "Premium Disk Supported".

On an existing cluster, if you are using VMSS, you can also check the storage tier in the portal under the VMSS "Storage" tab, or by issuing `az vmss list` (storageProfile.osDisk.managedDisk.storageAccountType). Otherwise simply check the disk type in the virtual machine nodes AKS creates.

Comment: Could we change vmss osDisk type to standard SSD or even HDD by az cli ?

Comment: created today a new Node pool with Standard_D4_v5 and end up with Standard HDD (wanted Standard SSD)

Comment: Seems like all the VM sizes mentioned in the portal with filter `Premium Storage: Not Supported`, when used to create a node pool, ends up using osDiskSku `Standard HDD`. Is there any size that uses Standard SSD by default?

Answer (score 1):

as far as I remember nodes are either standard or premium depending on the vm sku. if you are using a sku that supports premium disks it would use those. if you check [AKS api reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/managedclusters/createorupdate#managedclusteragentpoolprofile) for the agent pools, it has got no property for the disk type, so its being inferred for you.